# $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\in n\iff k\subsetneq n$ [Proof Verification and Suggestion for shorter or simpler proof]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof, peano-axioms

I'm not sure if my below proof contains subtle errors that I'm unable to recognize. Please have a check on it!

Furthermore, I found that my proof is long. Please suggest me any simpler or shorter proof. I believe that looking at your proofs help me learn a lot of valuable things.

Thank you so much!

---

Let $\mathbb N$ is the set of natural numbers by Von Neumann construction (https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Natural_number#/Formal_definitions).

**Theorem**: $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\in n\iff k\subsetneq n$.

---

*Lemma 1*: $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies k\subseteq n$.

> Let $T=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid \forall k \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies k\subseteq n\}$. It's clear that $0=\varnothing\in T$ by vacuity. Assume $n\in T$, then $\forall k \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies k\subseteq n$. For $k\in n+1=n\cup \{n\}$. There are two cases in total.
>
> If $k=n$, then $k\subseteq n\cup\{n\}=n+1$, hence $k\subseteq n+1$.
>
> The only other possibility is that $k\in n$, then $k\subseteq n$ [Since $n\in T$], hence $k\subseteq n+1$.
>
> Either way, $k\in n+1\implies k\subseteq n+1$. Thus $n+1\in T$. By principle of induction, $T=\mathbb N$, or equivalently *Lemma 1* is proved.

*Lemma 2*: $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies n\not\subseteq k$.

> Let $T=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid\forall k \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies n\not\subseteq k\}$. It's clear that $0=\varnothing\in T$ by vacuity. Assume $n\in T$, then $\forall k \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies n\not\subseteq k$. For $k\in n+1=n\cup \{n\}$. There are 2 cases in total.
>
> If $k=n$, then $n+1=n\cup \{n\}\not\subseteq k$ [If $n\cup \{n\}\subseteq k=n$, then $n\in n$, hence $n\not\subseteq n$, which is a contradiction].
>
> The only other possibility is that $k\in n$, then $n\not\subseteq k$ [Since $n\in T$], hence $n\cup \{n\}\not\subseteq k$, or $n+1\not\subseteq k$.
>
> Either way, $k\in n+1\implies n+1\not\subseteq k$. Thus $n+1\in T$. By principle of induction, $T=\mathbb N$, or equivalently *Lemma 2* is proved.

As a corollary of *Lemma 2*, $n\subseteq n\implies n\notin n$.

*Lemma 3*: $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies k\subsetneq n$.

> $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies k\subseteq n$ [From *Lemma 1*] and $n\not\subseteq k$ [From *Lemma 2*], so $k\in n\implies k\subsetneq n$.

*Lemma 4*: $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\subsetneq n\implies k+1\subseteq n$.

> Let $T=\{n\in\mathbb N\mid \forall k \in\mathbb N:k\subsetneq n\implies k+1\subseteq n\}$. It's clear that $0=\varnothing\in T$ by vacuity. Assume $n\in T$, then $\forall k \in\mathbb N:k\subsetneq n\implies k+1\subseteq n$. For $k\subsetneq n+1=n\cup\{n\}$. There are two cases in total.
>
> If $n\in k$, then $n\subsetneq k\subsetneq n\cup\{n\}\subseteq k$. Thus $k\subsetneq k$, which is impossible to happen. So this case is not possible.
>
> If $n\notin k$, then $k\subseteq n$. If $k=n$, then $k+1=n+1$, hence $k+1\subseteq n+1$. If $k\subsetneq n$, then $k+1\subseteq n$ [Since $n\in T$], hence $k+1\subseteq n\cup\{n\}=n+1$.
>
> Either way, $\forall k \in\mathbb N:k\subsetneq n+1\implies k+1\subseteq n+1$. Thus $n+1\in T$. By principle of induction, $T=\mathbb N$, or equivalently *Lemma 4* is proved.

Now we use above *Lemmas* to prove the **Theorem**. The statement $(\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\in n\implies k\subsetneq n)$ is true by *Lemma 3*. Next, we prove the converse i.e. $\forall k,n \in\mathbb N:k\subsetneq n\implies k\in n$. We have that $k\subsetneq n\implies k+1=k\cup\{k\}\subseteq n$ [By *Lemma 4*] $\implies\{k\}\subseteq n\implies k\in n$. In short, $k\subsetneq n\implies k\in n$. Thus the converse statement is proved too. Finally, the **Theorem** is proved. $\Box$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\Bbb N$(or $\omega$ or $\aleph_0$) is a set of ordinals(transitive set that is stricly well ordered under $\in$) by definition.

So: $k\in n\implies\forall a\in k (a\in n)\implies k\subseteq n$

Because $n$ is an ordinal so is $n+1$, hence, because $\in$ is strictly well ordered on $n+1$ and $n\in n+1$, $n\notin n$.

The other direction: if $a,b$ are ordinals such that $b\subsetneq a$ then take $A=a\setminus b$ and take the least element in that set and call it $c$, clearly $c\in a$, I'll now show that $c=b$:

Given $d\in c$ we have $d\in b$, otherwise $d$ is a smaller than $c$ and in $A$ and we get contradiction, so $c\subseteq b$

Given $d\in b$ then $d\in c$, otherwise we have(from the well ordering) $c\in d$ that implies $c\in b\implies c\notin A$. Hence $b\subseteq c$

And thus $b=c\in a$

Comment: Thank you @Holo, I got your proof. Did you see any mistake in my proof?

Comment: @LEANHDUNG apart from saying "by vacuity" instead of "vacuously": in lemma 2 "...$n∈n$ , hence $n⊈n$" this need a proof. overall there are some places where you could have wrote less(for example you could done lemma 4 without breaking it to cases), but apart from the mistake in lemma 2 I couldn't find any other mistakes

Comment: @LEANHDUNG never mind that, this is not a mistake, you proof is needlessly long but is good

Comment: Hi @Holo, I posted a question regarding a property of natural numbers at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2838081/each-natural-number-is-equal-to-the-set-of-all-natural-numbers-less-than-it, but I've not received any question. If you have some free time, please have a look at it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @LEANHDUNG I answered it, usually more people will tend to answer you if you add your thoughts, for example, why do you think there is something wrong or why are you not sure about the answer

Comment: From now on, I will try to add my thought to make reading easier :) Thank you for your useful recommendation!

Comment: Hi @Holo, I think that your proof might be circular. Please check my reasoning: To show that $\mathbb N$ is a set of ordinals, we must prove the transitivity of $\mathbb N$, i.e. $\forall m,n\in\mathbb N,m\in n\iff m\subsetneq n$ (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2148742/the-set-of-natural-numbers-is-ordinal). And the transitivity of $\mathbb N$ is what i'm trying to prove. But you are using the direct corollary of transitivity of $\mathbb N$ (that is, $\mathbb N$ is a set of ordinals) to prove the transitivity of $\mathbb N$.

Comment: @LEANHDUNG yes and no, this is heavily depends on how you define $\Bbb N$ in the start of the post I stated that $\Bbb N$ is defined as a set of ordinals. It is true that I did not notice what definition you used and hence using your definition it create circular logic. But you can easily prove that if $A$ is ordinal then $A+1$ is an ordinal use principle of induction(vacuously $\emptyset$ is an ordinal) and $\Bbb N$ is a set of ordinals

Comment: Note the definition of ordinal I use is what I wrote in the post